# Add reaction in jda to Message by messageid

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

My problem is, that my code, especially `tc.addReactionById(messageID, emote);`, dont adds a reaction. The whole code is following!

```
if(args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(prefix + "system") && args[1].equalsIgnoreCase("radd")){
            if(args.length == 6){
                Message message = event.getMessage();
                List<TextChannel> channels = event.getMessage().getMentionedChannels();
                List<Role> roles = message.getMentionedRoles();

                if(!channels.isEmpty() && !roles.isEmpty()){
                    TextChannel tc = event.getMessage().getMentionedChannels().get(0);
                    Role role = roles.get(0);
                    String messageIDString = args[2];
                    try{
                        long messageID = Long.parseLong(messageIDString);
                        String emote = args[5];
                        tc.addReactionById(messageID, emote);
                        eb.setAuthor("Oni System");
                        eb.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                        eb.setDescription(emote);
                        eb.setFooter("Oni System | ©ONI", "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/810910771557957672/810927512892604416/Bot.png?width=676&height=676");
                        channel.sendMessage(eb.build()).queue();
                        LiteSQL.onUpdate("INSERT INTO reactionroles(guildid, channelid, messageid, emoji, roleid) VALUES(" + event.getGuild().getIdLong() + ", " + tc.getIdLong() + ", " + messageID + ", '" + emote +"', " + role.getIdLong() + ")");
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
            else{
                eb.setAuthor("Oni System");
                eb.setColor(Color.RED);
                eb.setDescription(userMent + " bitte benutze !system radd <messageid> <@role>  <channel> <emoji>");
                eb.setFooter("Oni System | ©ONI", "https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/810910771557957672/810927512892604416/Bot.png?width=676&height=676");
                channel.sendMessage(eb.build()).queue();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You forgot to call queue() on the RestAction. See also [Troubleshooting](https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/19%29-Troubleshooting#nothing-happens-when-using-x)

Comment: Read this please [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) and switch to [PreparedStatements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 0):

`addReactionById` is a RestAction in the JDA library, so you will need to queue the operation.

Replace

```java
tc.addReactionById(messageID, emote);
```

with

```java
tc.addReactionById(messageID, emote).queue();
```

Assuming the `messageID` and `emote` arguments are valid, the call to `.queue()` should process the reaction. In particular, `emote` needs to be one of either:

- An Emote object created by JDA (usually these are custom server emotes), or
- A Unicode string of the emoji you want to add

See the [MessageChannel documentation](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageChannel.html) for more info.